# Setting up FetchedResultsController with multiple entities

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have several entities in `Core Data`. One is called `EventCluster` and is used to hold up and structure the `Event` objects.

All I want to do in my `UITableView` is pretty simple - I want `UITableViewSections` to be the corresponding `EventCluster` objects and each row of the section to be an `Event` object which will be sorted by `eventID` value.

Right now all I do is this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"eventID" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Is there a convenient way to set up the `NSFetchedResultsController` here to include the `EventCluster` structure?

Comment: Try setting sectionNameKeyPath to @"EventCluster"

Comment: @Koen, nah, that doesn't work. Crashes with: `the entity Event is not key value coding-compliant for the key "EventCluster"` as expected.

Comment: They don't have a relationship in your model?

Comment: They do, `EventCluster` is indeed a `parentCluster` property for `Event`. The thing is I have to sort `EventCluster` objects as well and then sort `Event` objects inside it.

Comment: Then set the sectionNameKeyPath to @"parentCluster".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query for events and use sectionNameKeyPath: to point to a custom method on EventCluster that returns a unique NSString for each EventCluster:

```
parentCluster:@"parentCluster.customMethod"
```

and this (I wrote this by heart, but you get the idea)

```
@implementation EventCluster (CategoryName)

- (NSString *)customMethod
{
    return self.objectID.URIRepresentation.absoluteString;
}

@end
```